# Why is hibernate saying class doesn't have an id when testing an extended entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, h2, mappedsuperclass

I am trying to set up an h2 database for testing. Problem is that when I try to run a test I get an error:  `ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()` even though the super class has the id. Is this just a bad entity design or is something wrong with me configuration?

superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Data {
    
    @Id
    protected Long NB_ID;
    protected String FG_STATUS;
    @Column(name="FG_ETAT")
    protected String FG_ETAT;
    protected String LB_ETAT;

getters/setters
```

subclass:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="ERESIS.ECH_HISEXPCOM")
    public class CustomerDelivery extends Data{
        
        protected String CD_COM1;
        protected Integer NO_LIGNE;
        protected String CD_MAT;
        protected Double QT_NET;

 getters/setters
```

my config:

```
nav.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:sanders_20180813_nemanja;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
nav.datasource.username=sa
nav.datasource.password=sa
nav.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
nav.datasource.max-idle=2
nav.datasource.min-idle=2
nav.datasource.initial-size=2

nav.jpa.show-sql=true
nav.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
nav.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
nav.jpa.properties.connection.CharSet=utf8
nav.jpa.properties.connection.characterEncoding=utf8
nav.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true

nut.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:NUTRICIEL_SYNC;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
nut.datasource.username=sa
nut.datasource.password=sa
nut.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
nut.datasource.max-idle=2
nut.datasource.min-idle=2
nut.datasource.initial-size=2
nut.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
#nut.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL

nut.jpa.show-sql=true
nut.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
nut.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
nut.jpa.properties.connection.CharSet=utf8
nut.jpa.properties.connection.characterEncoding=utf8
nut.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
```

Comment: The superclass may have the `id`-attribute, but is not marked as `@GeneratedValue`, hence we have to explicitly set the `id`-attribute. --- A remark on your code: fields in java should be written in `camelCase`, only constants should be written in `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`.

Comment: That seems to be it, thanks.